# Yii2: Why is bootstrap.css loaded multiple times in Firefox?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, yii2

When I call the pages of my Yii 2 web application in Firefox `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap.css.map` gets loaded six times with each request. In Chrome and Opera this doesn't happen.

On Fedora 20 with Firefox 33.1 and Yii 2.0.1. Server is on the same machine: Apache 2.4.10 with PHP 5.5.18.

What could be the reason? I have also Phusion_Passenger 4.0.42 installed. Could this cause the problem (but only with Firefox?)?

Comment: Is this when using active forms?

Comment: No, also without active forms.

Comment: Hmm, do your css files have a postfix attached to their sources as in of `src="some/link.css?<numbers>"` ?

Comment: No, the only difference that I see in the network analysis of firefox is that the requests' keep-alive max value differs (value 95 - 100). But they all get 200 responses.

Comment: My only other idea is if you're serving files from a shared-folder, to copy/change the files to C:/ or somewhere else.... Could be that virtual box is being finicky as per usual. I'm guessing you're on a Windows machine if this works.

Comment: Try disableing the addons 1 at a time and testing again. One of the addons might be the problem.

Comment: I'm on Fedora (Linux). I tried disabling all add-ons but it didn't help. However, I have another Firefox profile on my system and with this the problem doesn't exist. So it seems that it has something to do with this Firefox profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to has something to do with the web development tools of Firefox. With Firebug the file is loaded only once, like it should be, but only as long as the Network monitor (or is it called Network analysis in English? In German it is Netzwerkanalyse) of Firefox is not opened at the same time! As soon as the network monitor is opened too, Firebug shows the reloading of the same file as well.

I don't know if it is a bug or if it is a (required) side effect.

I've found this behavior with different Firefox instances (not only one like I've stated in the question comments first).

Comment: Quick note: as of October 18th 2015, Firefox 40.0.3, this is still the case.